# Migrating to Vite from Vue CLI (Vue 3): Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'default' of 'undefined' as it is undefined

Tags: vuejs3, vite

I was migrating my Vue 3 project from Vue CLI to Vite and upon testing, I kept getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'default' of 'undefined' as it is undefined.

My .vue file that is having the problem looks like this:

```js
<template>
    <h1>Projects</h1>

    <ProjectList/>
</template>

<script>
import ProjectList from '@/components/ProjectList';

export default {
    components: {ProjectList},
    setup() {
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that I forgot to add the .vue extension in my import.

```js
import ProjectList from '@/components/ProjectList.vue';
```